# how to simultaneously create rtsp and livehttp video streams in vlc from the same live source?

Tags: streaming, vlc

I want to simultaneously create rtsp and livehttp video streams from the same live H.264 source in cvlc. I can individually create either kind of stream just fine, and I can also create two rtsp streams simultaneously using the 'duplicate' tag, so my basic setup is right. Something is wrong when I try to do the two kinds of streams at the same time in a single command.

This runs in linux and the commands are written in bash. My frame rate, $fps, is 10 fps. /home/vout1 is my live H.264 source. Folders and the server URL are defined by variables. Note that I had to add dst= when I went from the single command to the combined command.

Here's the working rtsp command:

```
cvlc -vvv stream:///home/vout1 --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' --demux=h264 --h264-fps=$fps
```

Here's the working livehttp command:

```
cvlc -vvv stream:///home/vout1 --sout "#standard{access=livehttp{seglen=5,delsegs=true,numsegs=2,index=$streaming_video_folder/stream.m3u8,index-url=$server_URL/stream-###.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=$streaming_video_folder/stream-###.ts}}" --h264-fps=$fps --demux=h264
```

Here's a working command that creates two rtsp streams:

```
cvlc -vvv stream:///home/vout1 --sout '#duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/},dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:9554/}}' :demux=h264 :h264-fps=$fps
```

Here's the non-working combined, rtsp and livehttp command:

```
cvlc -vvv stream:///home/vout1 --sout '#duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/},dst=standard{access=livehttp{seglen=5,delsegs=true,numsegs=2,index=$streaming_video_folder/stream.m3u8,index-url=$server_url/stream-###.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=$streaming_video_folder/stream-###.ts}}' :demux=h264 :h264-fps=$fps
```

I don't get any streams and I get a multitude of these errors:

```
[0xca4540] access_output_livehttp access out error: cannot open `-treaming_video_folder/stream-001.ts' (No such file or directory)
```

For some reason, the previously working variable name, $streaming_video_folder, has been transformed to the erroneous, -treaming_video_folder.

Can someone tell me the proper syntax for the combined command ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your working livehttp command has double quotes, and your non-working duplicate command has single quotes.  Your shell is interpolating the variables in the double-quote example but passing them as a string literal in the latter case.  You can see what the shell is doing by changing `cvlc` to `echo`.